# How to implement jszip in react.js

Tags: javascript, api, promise, redux-saga, jszip

I am trying to zip a list of files before sending out through the http request. But I got stuck here.

```
export default function zipTargetFiles(files) {
    if (files.length <= 1) {
        return files;
    } else {
        const zip = require('jszip')();
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            zip.file(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }
    return zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"});
}
```

}

Basically, the function takes in a list of files and tries to zip them into one single .zip file. But when i send it out as formed data, it gave the error that the submitted data was not a file.

I checked the payload in the header and the target field is as `[object Promise]`. How do I to truly return a .zip file?

Now I am able to catch the zip file in Redux-saga but it doesn't give an extension when I saved it in my database, instead it only give the name as 'blob'.

**saga.js**

```
const file = yield call(zipTargetFiles, files);
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("coversheet", file);
const reponse = yield call(apiRequest, formData);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whats happening is that `.generateAsync` is returning a promise. You will have to wait until the promise is either fulfilled or rejected before being able to work with the data.

Promises is a core concept in JS when working with async operations. You can read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
import zipTargetFiles from '/path'

zipTargetFiles( data ).then(file => {
 // Access your file here
})
```

Comment: Got it! But how can I clarify the name of the file? Right now when I save it in my backend, it only appears as 'blob' without extension .zip

Answer (score 4):

To download and name the .zip folder you will need saveAs() from [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2)

```
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

  zip
    .generateAsync({
      type: "blob"
    })
    .then(content => {
      saveAs(content, "fileName.zip");
    });
```