# Return JSZip zip file in React

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, jszip

I have a function that zips a file, but atm it returns a promise. I tried to implement this: [jszip stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52882703/how-to-implement-jszip-in-react-js) but it still returns the promise, unresolved.

I'm not that familiar with promises, and not at all familiar with jsZIP - how do I get this function to return the zipped file?

```
const getZip = (url) => {
        setLoadingStatus('zipping...')
        let zip = new JSZip();
        console.log("TYPOF URL", url, typeof url)
        zip.file("Report", url)
        var promise = null;
        if (JSZip.support.uint8array) {
        promise = zip.generateAsync({type : "uint8array"}).then(content => {
            saveAs(content, "Report.zip");
          });
        } else {
        promise = zip.generateAsync({type : "string"}).then(content => {
            saveAs(content, "Report.zip");
          });
        }
        console.log("TYPEOF PROMISE", promise, typeof promise) //typeof is always promise
        return promise
    }
```

With async await:

```
    async function getZip(url){
    setLoadingStatus('zipping...')
    let zip = new JSZip();
    console.log("TYPOF URL", url, typeof url)
    zip.file("Report", url)
    var content = null;
    if (JSZip.support.uint8array) {
        content = await zip.generateAsync({type : "uint8array"}).then(content => {
            saveAs(content, "Report.zip");
          })
    } else {
        content = await zip.generateAsync({type : "string"}).then(content => {
            saveAs(content, "Report.zip");
          })
    }
    return content
}
```

The function that calls getZip() is:

```
const createURL = useCallback((node, reportHeight, reportWidth, imgHeight) => {

        domtoimage.toJpeg(node, {width: reportInViewerRef.current.offsetWidth, height: reportInViewerRef.current.scrollHeight})
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [reportWidth, imgHeight]);
        setLoadingStatus('pdf created')
        pdf.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 0, -12, reportWidth, reportHeight );
        setLoadingStatus('image added')
        let fileName = getUniqueFilename()
        let base64pdf = getZip(btoa(fileName, pdf.output()));
        console.log("ZIP FILE =================", base64pdf)
        let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        setLoadingStatus('uploading...')
        let fileLocation = '/pdfs/' + fileName + '.zip'
        let reportPdfRef = storageRef.child(fileLocation);
        reportPdfRef.putString(base64pdf, 'base64').then(function() {
            console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!', reportPdfRef,
            reportPdfRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                setLoadingStatus('linking...')
                setTemplateParams({
                    to: sessionData.customerEmail,
                    customers: name, 
                    adviser: adviserFullName,
                    adviserEmail: adviserEmail,
                    adviserAvatar: adviserAvatar,
                    content: url

                }) 
                firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('sessions')
                .doc(sessionData.id)
                .update({
                    'pdfDownloadURL': url
                }).then(function() {
                    setLoadingStatus('sending email')
                    setSendingEmail(false);
                  });
              }).catch(function(error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                  case 'storage/object-not-found':
                        console.log("FILE DOES NOT EXIST")
                    break;
                  case 'storage/unauthorized':
                        console.log("USER DOES NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO ACCESS THIS FILE")
                    break;

                  case 'storage/canceled':
                        console.log("USER CANCELLED THE UPLOAD")
                    break;
                  case 'storage/unknown':
                        console.log("SERVER ERROR")
                    break;
                }
              })
            )
          });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
        });
}, [])
```

Comment: Simplest would be to just use async/await. So make the function async and then do something like `let content= await zip.generateAsync(...); saveAs(content, "Report.zip");` and then you can return the content if it's needed elsewhere.

Comment: Can you flesh it out with an example? Sorry I'm just not that familiar with async await

Comment: Why did you tag the question with `reactjs`? I can't see anything related to react. If you intend to use this inside of a react component and you don't know how please also add the relevant code. Otherwise just remove the tag. As you seem to call `setLoadingStatus` I guess this function is defined inside of a component using `useState`?

Comment: That literally is an example haha it's what you need. So in the function definition you put `async`, like so: `const getZip = async (url)...` and then you use that code in my first comment. The "content" that you had in your `.then` is what turns into the return value of the awaited call, that's why there's no `promise` variable needed now, just rename that to `content`.

Comment: Where do you call `getZip`? Please also show the surrounding component.

Comment: Hmmm Jaycee444 that's still returning the promise not waiting to complete - will put new code in question

Comment: @Davtho1983 We need to know why you want to return the zip. So please also share the code that uses `getZip`. As the zip creation is async you can't just use it in a synchronous way. Your code using `getZip` also needs to be async. As you tagged the question with `reactjs` also show the component. You may not even need to return the zip but take an entirely different approach.

Comment: Ok have added the function that calls getZip() - I need to upload zip to firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the zip creation is async the code handling it also needs to be async. Make your 
`createURL` handler async and `await` the zip inside of it:

```
const createURL = useCallback(async (node, reportHeight, reportWidth, imgHeight) => {
    try {
        const dataUrl = await domtoimage.toJpeg(node, {width: reportInViewerRef.current.offsetWidth, height: reportInViewerRef.current.scrollHeight})
    } catch (error) {
        return console.error('oops, something went wrong!', error);
    }

    // ... you can use dataUrl from here

    let base64pdf = await getZip(btoa(fileName, pdf.output()));

    // ... do something with the zip file
}
```

Generally speaking if an async function returns something the code using it also needs to be async.

Comment: That definitely makes sense - it's not letting me make my useCallback async tho?

Comment: @Davtho1983 Where did you put the `async` keyword? It has to be directly before your arrow function, **not** before `useCallback`. This definitely works. What do you mean with *it's not letting me*? Is there an error? Is the `createURL` handler called as an event handler?

Comment: I have const createURL = useCallback(async (node, reportHeight, reportWidth, imgHeight) => { ... let base64pdf = await getZip(btoa(fileName, pdf.output())); ... the error I get is Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: Is it because it's inside a then?

Comment: @Davtho1983 Yes that may be the reason. You can also use async/await there. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @Davtho1983 To keep it consistent you can use async/await for `toJpeg` too. Otherwise you will also have to make your handler in `.then()` async.